# Error on JAX-RS webservice startup

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I refactored an working `JAX-RS`, Jersey implementation, webservice in order to isolate it entities so them can be used as a library, I also changed the project and package name, now when I try to get tomcat up I got this `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` **error**:

```
 org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.RankedProvider.getContractTypes()Ljava/util/Set;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.filterNameBound(ApplicationHandler.java:801)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.getProcessingProviders(ApplicationHandler.java:702)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:484)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:166)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:327)
```

I have googled but cant find anything related to this specific error

Those are the dependencies of the entity project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>br.com.logtec</groupId>
<artifactId>zaprango-entity</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>

        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>

        <properties>
            <qbeasy.version>1.1</qbeasy.version>
            <maven-compiler.version>1.8</maven-compiler.version>
            <uk.co.jemos.podam.podam.version>4.7.3.RELEASE</uk.co.jemos.podam.podam.version>
        </properties>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${maven-compiler.version}</source>
                        <target>${maven-compiler.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>          
        </build>

        <dependencies>
            <!-- QBEasy -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>br.com.boilerplatecorp</groupId>
                <artifactId>qbeasy</artifactId>
                <version>${qbeasy.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- PoDam -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>uk.co.jemos.podam</groupId>
                <artifactId>podam</artifactId>
                <version>${uk.co.jemos.podam.podam.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>tomcat</id>

        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>

        <properties>
            <jersey-servlet.version>2.16</jersey-servlet.version>
            <org.hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</org.hibernate.version>
            <jackson.version>2.16</jackson.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <!-- JPA/Hibernate Impl -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Jackson -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- JAX-RS/Jersey Impl -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey-servlet.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

and those are the ws dependencies:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>logtec</groupId>
<artifactId>zaprango-ws</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>

        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>

        <properties>
            <!-- Propriedades do projeto -->
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
            <maven.compiler.fork>true</maven.compiler.fork>

            <!-- Dependencias -->
            <jee.version>7.0</jee.version>
            <qbeasy.version>1.1</qbeasy.version>
            <modelmapper.version>0.7.3</modelmapper.version>
            <maven-compiler.version>1.8</maven-compiler.version>
        </properties>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${maven-compiler.version}</source>
                        <target>${maven-compiler.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>          
        </build>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>br.com.logtec</groupId>
                <artifactId>zaprango-entity</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- JEE 7 API -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                <version>${jee.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Model Mapper -->
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
              <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
              <version>${modelmapper.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                <version>1.10</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>tomcat</id>

        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>

        <properties>
            <org.postgresql.jdbc.version>9.3-1102-jdbc4</org.postgresql.jdbc.version>
            <weld.version>2.2.4.Final</weld.version>
            <jersey-cdi.version>2.14</jersey-cdi.version>
            <org.hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</org.hibernate.version>
            <org.hibernate-validator.version>5.1.1.Final</org.hibernate-validator.version>
            <c3p0.version>4.3.8.Final</c3p0.version>
            <deltaspike.version>1.2.1</deltaspike.version>
            <jackson.version>2.16</jackson.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <!-- CDI/ Weld Impl -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
                <version>${weld.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Possibilitando o uso de de CDI com o Jersey -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers.glassfish</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-gf-cdi</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey-cdi.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- JDBC Driver -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>${org.postgresql.jdbc.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Bean Validation/Hibernate Impl -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>${org.hibernate-validator.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- c3p0 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
                <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>test</id>

        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>

        <properties>
            <junit.junit.version>4.12</junit.junit.version>
            <uk.co.jemos.podam.podam.version>4.7.3.RELEASE</uk.co.jemos.podam.podam.version>
            <arquillian-bom.version>1.1.7.Final</arquillian-bom.version>
            <surefire.version>2.17</surefire.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                    <version>${arquillian-bom.version}</version>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                    <type>pom</type>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
                    <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-bom</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.0-alpha-5</version>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                    <type>pom</type>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${surefire.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

        <dependencies>
            <!-- JUnit -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.junit.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Integracao JUnit e Arquillian -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
                <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.4</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
                <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-api</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
                <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
                <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- PoDam -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>uk.co.jemos.podam</groupId>
                <artifactId>podam</artifactId>
                <version>${uk.co.jemos.podam.podam.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Are you a beginner on development related to web services ?

Comment: well, not a beginner.. but not also a veteran, but why?

Comment: Don't use maven in that case ,create your dynamic web project and add your jersey jar files into your WEB-INF/lib folder and code the purpose for what you want your web services to do.

Comment: sorry, but what u said makes no sense to me, what is the diference of using or not maven, all it does is help me managing my dependencies, I dont got your point..

Answer (score 3):

From my experience this error usually happens when you are using incompatible versions of libraries. Check that all Jersey libraries you are using are compatible and there are no jar of other versions in classpath.
I found that class you mentioned is in 'jax-rs-ri' dependency, it could be good start for checking probably.
Good luck!

Comment: I agree with the mixing of versions. @MarcosJ.CKichel you should update your post to show your dependencies/jars

Comment: Just did it @peeskillet hope it helps

Comment: @MarcosJ.CKichel Look into [this](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/migration.html#mig-2.15). Jersey 2.15+ changed the CDI support artfiact.

Comment: Anyway, if that was the case, it should't be working as it is, it is using the same cdi support. Very strange, I will try this out

Comment: @MarcosJ.CKichel My guess is you are using 2.14 for that artifact because you didn't know of the change. That artifact is not produced after 2.14. You are using Jersey 2.16. You shouldn't mix Jersey versions. Change the artifact and use 2.16, and see what happens